# Identify this plant(s) mixed with a dwarf bamboo

Tags: identification

At first there was much less of the heart-shaped leaves and more bamboo leaves but the bamboo mostly died off and the heart-shaped leaves mostly took over the pot.

I was under the impression that it was part of the bamboo plant at first but I don't think that is the case as it started to propagate on it's own and is producing what appear to be seed pods.

There may be more than 1 other plant in here also as seen in the first and third picture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see more plants than you mentioned: Picture 1: bamboo, wood sorrel *and something with dark green, slightly "hairy" oval leaves*, picture 2: b., w.s. *and something with compound leaves (three on a stem) plus some seedlings*, picture 3: b., w.s. *and something lanceolate*.

Comment: The lanceolate leaves are actually bamboo - if you want to keep the bamboo, suggest you turn it all out of the pot, extract the invading 'weed' plants and repot the bamboo on its own.

Comment: @Bamboo That, or simply remove the weeds with their roots.

Comment: @J. Musser - looks like it needs a bigger pot anyway though, or at least more root room, and where there's one weed coming through, hundreds wait in the wings...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One, I *can* identify:
The one with the three heart-shaped leaves is some kind of oxalis (wood sorrel).

For the last one I'll venture *a wild guess*:
Perhaps some kind of epilobium (willowherb) - looks a lot like the weeds I pluck from my yard (but that's in Germany...)? But it's rather small and not too distinct.